# WPF MVVM: How to disable clicked button and enable all other buttons?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a group of buttons that are enabled whenever one of the buttons is clicked and the clicked one is disabled.

```
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource BigGrayButton}" Command="{Binding Path=NavigatePage}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableButton}"/>
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource BigGrayButton}" Command="{Binding Path=NavigatePage}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableButton}"/>
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource BigGrayButton}" Command="{Binding Path=NavigatePage}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableButton}"/>
<Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Style="{StaticResource BigGrayButton}" Command="{Binding Path=NavigatePage}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EnableButton}"/>
```

The problem is using the above code result in disabling all buttons when setting **EnableButton** to false after executing the command.

Comment: Usually, you just ensure that [CanExecute is false for that button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476708/87698). Do you really have the same command bound to all the buttons? If yes, how do you determine which one was clicked (because, I assume that it makes a difference to your app)? If all the buttons are exactly the same, why do you have 4 of them instead of 1?

Comment: Try `RadioButton`, It's very fit for this situation

Comment: The problem is that all buttons are disabled, but what I want is to disable only clicked one and enable all others.

Comment: Then you'll have to have one command per button?

Comment: You can always just add a click even on to your buttons, put them under one control for simplicity, get that control, dissable all other buttons and enable only your button

Comment: @HmH: Yes, I understood that. Please answer the questions in my comment, it will help us understand your requirements better.

Comment: What is your viewmodel structure? Any list or individual properties ?

Comment: You can't distinguish each button from the other else in this way. Try to use at least a command parameter for each button. Give us at least the command code in the vm

Comment: @Heinzi Yes and each one is associated with a parameter. Each button shows different page that's why I need 4 buttons, mostly it's like a dashboard.

Comment: @HmH: Ah, I see, so the buttons are basically toggle buttons for choosing the page to be shown, right? In that case, the easiest solution would be to have `CanExecute` return `false`, if the parameter equals the currently shown page, and `true` otherwise. You won't need `IsEnabled` at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I said, why not try `RadioButton`?

If you only want to achieve this "feature", this is too easy - even don't need involve MVVM

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
        <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="BaseButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <!--<Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>-->
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton Content="Button1" Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Button2" Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Button3" Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"/>
    <RadioButton Content="Button4" Style="{StaticResource BaseButtonStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Preview:
[image]

---

Then you can setting `CommandParameter` for each button to tell the backend code which button was pressed.

You don't need to write any complicated logic to implement this feature. Why not try it?

Comment: +1 because this doesn't require writing out the custom logic because it's already implemented, *and* it allows for easy styling.

Comment: It seems the best solution with minimum code, even though I'm still looking to implement this behavior with regular button using mvvm.

Comment: Here has a car, why you need to reinvent the wheel? :-)

Comment: For some more: if you acturaly want to use MVVM, try to write a style on `ListBox`