# How to disable a button until another button is clicked in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How to disable a button until another button is clicked in WPF MVVM ?

any solution ?

Comment: In the other button click event handler just write `buttonToBeDisabled.IsEnabled = false;`

Comment: If you're using MVVM you can simply set the ```CanExecute``` property to false. If bound correctly, your button will be disabled.

Comment: Please add some code. Did you bind the button to a command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF MVVM: How to disable clicked button and enable all other buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035045/wpf-mvvm-how-to-disable-clicked-button-and-enable-all-other-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

What was suggested in one of the comments: [How to disable a button until another button is clicked in WPF MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317324/how-to-disable-a-button-until-another-button-is-clicked-in-wpf-mvvm#comment104835774_59317324) is a possible solution, however it's not MVVM and it does quite opposite to what you want to achieve.

You can also do the following:

- define a dependency property `IsAnotherButtonClicked` in your code and set it to false
- bind *a button's* `.IsEnabled` property to the defined dependency property in XAML
- in *another button's* `Click` event handler make sure that you set the `IsAnotherButtonClicked` to `true`